# Pork belly strips and ribs

Tags: pork, grilling, smoking, ribs, pork-belly

I’d like to know if I can safely lay down pork belly slices on top of pork ribs while smoking? I’m using a pellet grill/smoker at 200-225 degrees for 6 hours.

Comment: Can you describe what you plan to do?  Are you planning on adding the slices and ribs together at the -6 hour point or adding them later? If later, how much later?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be "safe". You can "safely" smoke both those items at those temperatures.